# How to use. Isempty in officejs

Tags: office-js

Office js help: I need to check if a paragraph contains a specific word! I have learned that paragraph.search("search keyword"). Isempty can serve the purpose. Somehow I can't get it to work. What's the proper sequence of code to check is a paragraph contains a specific word.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Can you show your code? Also, please specify in what way you "can't get it to work". Thanks.